# Javascript: How to get Substring of a string after // and before

Tags: javascript, string, split, substring

I have a string like **https://www.google.com**

I would like to get **www** so the substring of a string after `//` and before `.` (dot).

How can I do it?
I have tried using the `split` and `substring` method.
But it did not work.

Any help would be great.

Thank You.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please [edit] the question to add the code which you've tried.

Comment: If all you want to do is check if a string contains www you can use the following regex `/w{3}/g`

Comment: hi @XperiaReno and welcome to SO, please post the code you have tried, you shouldn't expect SO contributors to write a solution for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `replace()`

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/OFZtps/1)

```js
let result = 'https://www.google.com'.replace(/https?:\/\/([^.]+).*/, '$1')

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the URL browser API if available https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL

Another solution would be

```
var parser = document.createElement('a');
parser.href = "http://example.com:3000/pathname/?search=test#hash";

parser.protocol; // => "http:"
parser.hostname; // => "example.com"
parser.port;     // => "3000"
parser.pathname; // => "/pathname/"
parser.search;   // => "?search=test"
parser.hash;     // => "#hash"
parser.host;     // => "example.com:3000"
```